# in jQuery, how to select by class child elements inside a tag with id attribute?

Tags: jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

I have the following code

```
<tr id="myid">
<td>
<div>
...
<a href="" class="myclass"></a>
<a href="" class="myclass"></a>
<a href="" class="myclass"></a>
<a href="" class="myclass"></a>
<a href="" class="myclass"></a>
...
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="anotherid">
<td>
<div>
...
<a href="" class="myclass"></a>
<a href="" class="myclass"></a>
<a href="" class="myclass"></a>
<a href="" class="myclass"></a>
<a href="" class="myclass"></a>
...
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

and I'm trying to select A tags inside tag TR with ID "myid" attribute however the following code doesn't works:

```
$('#myid.myclass')
```

How can I select the A tags, using the TR ID?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this: `$('#myid .myclass')` - There should be a space between `#myid` and `.myclass`

Comment: @Max Just to expand slightly, what you currently have is looking for an element with both the ID and class given, i.e. `<foo id="myid" class="myclass"/>`

Comment: Yes. And the space in-between is to get any child matching the second part (.myclass) under any parent matching the first part (#myid).

Answer (score 1):

To select all `<a>` tags inside `#myid` regardless of nesting

```
$("a", "#myid")
```

Answer (score 0):

Its the same with CSS selectors. Your mark up means that you will need a space:

**Answer**

```
$('#myid .myclass')
```

**info**

this `$('#myid.myclass')` would mean that .myclass sits along side `#myid` like this:

```
<tr id="anotherid" class="myclass">
```